# Hibernate - generated value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am a newbie in hibernate and was playing around with it. For an unique field in an entity I am setting @GeneratedValue annotation to it. Suppose I have two entities , user and company and both having an unique id with @GeneratedValue annotation . When I save both the entities using hibernate session factory , the id generated are 1 and 2 respectively , where it should be 1 each for both entities. The next time when i save both , id generated are 3 and 4 .
So my guess is that , @GeneratedValue is working in db level and not table level. How to make it table level ?

Adding some codes and configs.

User entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

}
```

Company entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="company")

public class Company {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "id")
 private Integer id;
}
```

Saving using hibernate session

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    User user = new User();

    session.save(user);

    Company company = new Company();
    session.save(company);
```

Result

mysql> select * from user;

+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 234 |
+-----+

mysql> select * from company;

+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 235 |
+-----+

For the records , I am using hibernate-jpa-2.1-api ( 1.0.0.Draft-16 ) with hibernate 5.

Comment: It actually should generate 1 for both entities by default. Show us your config and some code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @`GenerateValue` annotation has an attribute called `strategy` that can hold   one of the the following strategies for generate the values for a primary keys:

- GenerationType.AUTO
- GenerationType.IDENTITY
- GenerationType.SEQUENCE
- GenerationType.TABLE

The `GenerationType.AUTO` use a global number generator for a database and it is the default, so if you only define @`GenerateValue` in the variable, you will have this behavior.

I recommend to you use one of the others in the list for obtain the result that you expect.For example, the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` allow you to generate the keys using the value from the table, only if the primary key is an auto-generated type. For example in Postgres, you can use the data type `SERIAL` and use this for generate the value of the key.

Comment: If i use that , the id is not generated and i am getting "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value " error while saving .
Code : 
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

Comment: As I said in the response the primary key data type in the database must be an autogenerated type, here are some examples of autogenerated types in some RDBMSs 
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Comment: FYI , the field is having AUTO_INCREMENT option . Hibernate is not allowing to save as the validation itself fails.